# Probability of skipping an interval given sum of uniform

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Given a sequence of i.i.d. uniform random variables in $(0,1)$, defining $S$ as the random variable equal to their sum, what is the probability that $S$ ever reaches some point inside the interval $(a,b)$?

In particular I interested in a subcase of this question where the interval is of the type $(a,1)$.

**Attempt**

So restring myself to the intervals in $(0,1)$, suppose WLOG that we are at $0$ and the interval is $(a,b)$ with $0 \le a \le b \le 1$, then after jumping I can have three cases: the jump goes over $b$ with probability $1-b$ (therefore the inside of the interval is never reached), jump inside the interval with probability $b-a$, jump somewhere before the left extreme of the interval with probability $a$ and when this happens the problem is the same with different extremes.

I modeled it with the following equation:
$$0 \le a \le b \le 1 \\
P(a,a) = 0 \\
P(0,b) = b \\
P(a,b)=b-a+a \int_0^a P(a-x,b-x)dx$$

I was able to solve this equation following this [Find closed formula for integral equation with two variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4653912/find-closed-formula-for-integral-equation-with-two-variables/4653944#4653944)
$$P(a,1)=1-a + a(1-a) \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{\frac{a^2}{2}} erf(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}})$$
this $P(a,1)$ should represent my probability of ever being inside the interval $(a,1)$, although from simulations it looks like it is incorrect.

Would you know where this modeling is incorrect? Is there another approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you right: we have $X_i$ iid uniform rv on $(0,1)$, let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ be their partial sums. We are interested in the event $ \exists n=1,2 \cdots s.t. a < S_n \le b$.

Let $g(x)$ be the probability of the desired event, given that we start from some partial $S_n = x$ with $0\le x <a$

In general

$$g(x)= \begin{cases}
\int_{x}^{a} g(u)\, du + \min(b,1+x) -a & \text{if } x +1>a\\
\int_{x}^{x+1} g(u) \, du  & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases} 
$$

The problem is simplified if we assume $0<a<1$ and $b=1$.

In that case

$$g(x) = \int_{x}^a g(u) du + 1 -a$$
which gives the diferential equation $g'(x) = -g(x) \implies g(x) = c e^{-x}$

Together with the initial condition $g(a)=1-a$, this gives

$$g(x) = (1-a) e^{a-x}$$

and hence the desired probability is $$g(0)=(1-a)e^a$$

Comment: This matches my simulations, thanks. Would you also know what was the issue with my model?

Comment: I see the difference, I multiplied by a factor $a$ or in general $a-x$ thinking that I needed to normalize or take the mean of the integral of $g$ in that range, why is that not needed?

Comment: @leonbloy one small question: how did you come up with such $g(x)$?